# Object assign produces undefined variable

Tags: javascript

So I've used `Object.assign()` before, with some success. However, I'm actually having issues now. I have a object:

```
let stats = {
      rounds: 0,
      userHits: 0,
      userDmgDelt: 0,
      userDmgTaken: 0,
      userCrits: 0,
      userMiss: 0,
      userDodge: 0,
      mobHits: 0,
      mobDmgDelt: 0,
      mobDmgTaken: 0,
      mobCrits: 0,
      mobMiss: 0,
      mobDodge: 0,
    };
```

Then I am attempting to do this:

```
stats = Object.assign(stats, {
    userMiss: userMiss++,
});
```

I thought that using the object inside the function would define it from its old value, which would be 0. I was wanting to avoid having to use long blocks of
`stats.Stat += 1` and what not.

Comment: What would those long blocks look like? What kind of situation causes all those stats to be increased at once?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `++stats.userMiss` to update `userMiss` value

```js
let stats = {
      rounds: 0,
      userHits: 0,
      userDmgDelt: 0,
      userDmgTaken: 0,
      userCrits: 0,
      userMiss: 0,
      userDodge: 0,
      mobHits: 0,
      mobDmgDelt: 0,
      mobDmgTaken: 0,
      mobCrits: 0,
      mobMiss: 0,
      mobDodge: 0,
    };

stats = Object.assign(stats, {
    userMiss: ++stats.userMiss
});

console.log(stats)
```

Comment: That should just be `++stats.userMiss;` without the `Object.assign`, then (which is what the OP wanted to avoid).

Answer (score 1):

`userMiss` is a key defined in the object `stats`.
So, to access that property you need to write `stats.userMiss`.

```
stats = Object.assign(stats, {
userMiss: stats.userMiss++,
```

});

Answer (score 1):

`userMiss` is not a standalone variable, so the expression `userMiss++` won't work. If you wanted to use Object.assign, you would have to use

```js
let stats = {
  rounds: 0,
  userHits: 0,
  userDmgDelt: 0,
  userDmgTaken: 0,
  userCrits: 0,
  userMiss: 0,
  userDodge: 0,
  mobHits: 0,
  mobDmgDelt: 0,
  mobDmgTaken: 0,
  mobCrits: 0,
  mobMiss: 0,
  mobDodge: 0,
};
stats = Object.assign(stats, {
  userMiss: stats.userMiss + 1,
});
console.log(stats);
```

but why not simply increment the property, avoiding `Object.assign` altogether?

```js
let stats = {
  rounds: 0,
  userHits: 0,
  userDmgDelt: 0,
  userDmgTaken: 0,
  userCrits: 0,
  userMiss: 0,
  userDodge: 0,
  mobHits: 0,
  mobDmgDelt: 0,
  mobDmgTaken: 0,
  mobCrits: 0,
  mobMiss: 0,
  mobDodge: 0,
};
stats.userMiss++;
console.log(stats);
```

Comment: I mean I could. The `stats.` part should have been obvious to me. I was told using Object.assign was a good way to handle all of it. But perhaps they meant when you are dealing with session objects. Anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is what you are trying to do:

```js
let stats = {
  rounds: 0, userHits: 0, userDmgDelt: 0, userDmgTaken: 0, userCrits: 0, userMiss: 0, userDodge: 0, mobHits: 0, mobDmgDelt: 0, mobDmgTaken: 0, mobCrits: 0, mobMiss: 0, mobDodge: 0,
};

stats = Object.assign(stats, {
    userMiss: ++stats.userMiss
});

console.log(stats)
```

But, this is a better **`immutable`** approach:

```js
let stats = {
      rounds: 0, userHits: 0, userDmgDelt: 0, userDmgTaken: 0, userCrits: 0, userMiss: 0, userDodge: 0, mobHits: 0, mobDmgDelt: 0, mobDmgTaken: 0, mobCrits: 0, mobMiss: 0, mobDodge: 0,
    };

let newStats = Object.assign({}, stats, {
    userMiss: ++stats.userMiss
});

console.log(newStats)
```

Or, you can also make use of **latest ES6** [`object destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) like this:

```js
let stats = {
  rounds: 0, userHits: 0, userDmgDelt: 0, userDmgTaken: 0, userCrits: 0, userMiss: 0, userDodge: 0, mobHits: 0, mobDmgDelt: 0, mobDmgTaken: 0, mobCrits: 0, mobMiss: 0, mobDodge: 0,
};

    let newStats = { ...stats, userMiss: ++stats.userMiss };

    console.log(newStats)
```